# Find specific server in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, ipad, client-server

Hi i am developing iPad client server based application. It is required in application that when application starts it searches for specific server. If server found then connect with it and start consuming webservices on that server.

The point is user should not enter IP address of server. Application search servers and connect with specific server. Is there anyway to find server.

Comment: what server ar you talking about?

Comment: It is an application for inhouse use purpose and it should find local servers in that company. then user should select the server and connect with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a technology called Bonjour which is designed for this kind of thing.
http://www.apple.com/support/bonjour/
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/iphone/9780470918029/bonjour-programming/browsing_for_services

If you want a simpler solution, you could just use a DNS entry with a CNAME or A record pointing to the server.